# Why is my first array list being changed to match my second array list

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

The assignment is to create two array lists from one list containing integers.  The new lists are counting the number of integers that are increasing and then the number of integers that are decreasing. Then I am to add the two "count" array lists to get a list with the total of up/down combined.  The count up generates properly, then the count down generates properly but when the count down is created, the count up is changed to match the count down so my total is wrong.  I can't figure out why the second arraylist automatically changes the first arraylist.

```
System.out.println("input list " + list);

// create an object to use the runList method to create the array list that will represent the runs list
temp listRunCount = new temp();
ArrayList<Integer> list_2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list_2=listRunCount.runLists(list);
System.out.println("zero list: " + list_2);
// create an object to use the listRunUpCount method to find all the run up elements of the input array list
ArrayList<Integer> listRunUpCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
listRunUpCount=listRunCount.findRuns(list, list_2, RUN_UP);
System.out.println("Run up   list "  + listRunUpCount);
// create an object to use the listRunUpCount method to find all the run up elements of the input array list
ArrayList<Integer> listRunDownCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
listRunDownCount=listRunCount.findRuns(list, list_2,RUN_DOWN);
System.out.println("Run Down list " + listRunDownCount);


//Method for counting

    public ArrayList<Integer> findRuns(ArrayList<Integer> list, ArrayList<Integer> lRCT,int pDir){
    ArrayList<Integer> listRunCountTemp = lRCT;
    int i=0, k=0;
    final int RUNS_UP = 10;
    final int RUNS_DOWN = 20;
    while(i<list.size()-1) 
    {
        if(pDir == RUNS_UP && list.get(i)<= list.get(i+1)) 
        {
            k++;
        }
        if(pDir == RUNS_DOWN && list.get(i)>= list.get(i+1))
        {
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(k!=0) 
            {
                listRunCountTemp.set(k-1,listRunCountTemp.get(k-1)+1);
                k=0;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
         return listRunCountTemp;
}
```

output of the arrays right after they are generated

```
Reading file...
input list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7]
zero list: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Run up   list [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Run Down list [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Run up   list [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: That's one ArrayList, not two. `ArrayList<Integer> listRunCountTemp = lRCT;` makes a new variable, but not a new list.

Comment: that method was an old method that did not calculate the runs correctly, this one works

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental issue:

```
listX = listY;
```

does not create a new list, and neither does it copy listY into listX; it simply gives an additional reference to an existing list.

`findRuns` returns the list that is passed to it as `1RCT`.

Every call to `findRuns` passes `list_2` as that argument.

Therefore `listRunUpCount` and `listRunDownCount` refer to the same list (`list_2`).  It does not matter that you assigned new ArrayLists to each of those variables before calling `findRuns`; those lists are not used.